# Do filters on a Boolean algebra also make a Boolean algebra?

Tags: order-theory, boolean-algebra, universal-algebra, filters

Let $\mathfrak{B}=(B,\bot,\top,\lnot,\wedge,\vee)$ be a boolean algebra. $B_F$ be the set of all filters on $\mathfrak B$. And for all filter $F$, $G$, $F \wedge_{B_F} G \colon= \mathbf C(F \cup G)$ in which $\mathbf C$ denotes the filter closure operator; $F \vee_{B_F} G \colon= F \cap G$; $0 \colon= B$, $1 \colon= \{\top\}$. Then $(B_F,0,1,\wedge_{B_F},\vee_{B_F})$ makes a complete lattice.

My question is can we add a negation in order to make it be a Boolean algebra?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is relatively easy to see that it does not matter whether we work with filters or with ideals.

The following is taken verbatim from
Steven R. Givant,Paul Richard Halmos: Introduction to Boolean Algebras
[p.167](http://books.google.com/books?id=ORILyf8sF2sC&pg=PA167):

> The ideals of a Boolean algebra form a complete, distributive lattice, but
>   they do not, in general, form a Boolean algebra. To give an example, it is
>   helpful to introduce some terminology. An ideal is maximal if it is a proper
>   ideal that is not properly included in any other proper ideal. We shall see in
>   the next chapter that an infinite Boolean algebra $B$ always has at least one
>   maximal ideal that is not principal. Assume this result for the moment. A
>   "complement" of such an ideal $M$ in the lattice of ideals of $B$ would be an
>   ideal $N$ with the property that
>   $$M\wedge N=\{0\} \qquad\text{and}\qquad M\vee N=B.$$
>   Suppose the first equality holds. If $q$ is any element in $N$, then $p \wedge q = 0$,
>   and therefore $p \le q'$, for every element $p$ in $M$, by Lemma 1. In other words,
>   the ideal $M$ is included in the principal ideal $(q')$. The two ideals must
>   be distinct, since $M$ is not principal. This forces $(q')$ to equal $B$, by the
>   maximality of $M$. In other words, $q' = 1$, and therefore $q = 0$. What has
>   been shown is that the meet $M\wedge N$ can be the trivial ideal only if $N$ itself is
>   trivial. In this case, of course, $M \vee N$ is $M$, not $B$. Conclusion: a maximal,
>   non-principal ideal does not have a complement in the lattice of ideals.

The existence of maximal ideals, which was used in the above excerpt, is guaranteed by [Boolean prime ideal theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_prime_ideal_theorem).

Comment: I understand. Thank you very much.